# Chrome DevTools getEventListeners works for $0 but not CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

There are several listings where either getEventListeners($0) or getEventListeners($("css-selector")) will show the events associated with the element. If I click on the element, it becomes $0 and I can see that in Elements Tab. I can then issue getEventListeners($0) from console and see the events. If I create a css-selector and test it on the Elements tab, I see my element highlighted, but if I use that selector e.g. getEventListeners($('#someid')) in the console I see nothing or {}. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The page apparently overrides `$` with jQuery. To get the actual element use `$('foo')[0]`

Comment: are you saying I should use getEventListeners($('foo')[0]) ?

Comment: I guess that's what i said, yes.

Comment: thx, that works Example on this page, inspect the [css] button above. I use the selector `a.post-tag.js-gps-track:first-of-type` which uniquely id's that element on this page. if i issue `getEventListeners($('a.post-tag.js-gps-track:first-of-type')) - i get  {}`.    `getEventListeners($0)` and `getEventListeners($('a.post-tag.js-gps-track:first-of-type')[0])` both return `{click: Array(1)}`